# Compare values from two Observables and return an Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular9

I am checking a condition and getting an `Observable<boolean>`:

```
let result = this.service.getCity().pipe(
  map((city: string) => city && city.toLowerCase() === ???) 
);
```

I need to check if the `city` equals:

```
this.authenticationService.getCity():
```

This method also returns and `Observable<boolean>`.

How can I combine the two observables and use both values in a condition?

I need to return an Observable at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Alternative to forkjoin**

If observable `completion` is not the trigger to compare both observables, you can use [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap)

```js
const { from, of } = rxjs;
const { map, switchMap, tap, take } = rxjs.operators;

const serviceCity$ = () => from(['Berlin', 'London', 'Paris']);
const authentificationCity$ = () => of('london');

const result$ = serviceCity$().pipe(
  map(city => city && city.toLowerCase()),
  switchMap(city => authentificationCity$().pipe(
    map(authCity => city === authCity),
    take(1),
  ))
);

result$.subscribe(v => console.log('authentification city equals london: ', v));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

**Info**

- `serviceCity$` and `authentificationCity$` equal your `service.getCity()` and `this.authenticationService.getCity()`
- I assumed both functions return a `string` and you want to compare both `strings`. If you want to compare two `pre-mapped` values then explain me and I will update the code.
- `result$` will fire whenever `serviceCity$` emits followed by an emit of `authentificationCity$`
- `take(1)` avoids the `result$` being triggered by `authentificationCity$` instead of `serviceCity$`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this.service.getCity()` and `this.authenticationService.getCity()` returns singular object/string based on how you named it.

You can use `forkJoin` operator. Here's an example

```
const source1 = of("CityName");
const source2 = of("CityName");

forkJoin({
  source1,
  source2
}).pipe(
  map((x: {source1, source2}) => x.source1 === x.source2)
).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-luncbd

Comment: Is it valid to rely on the completion of two service observables? If it's wanted to use only one emit (source1 + source2) I would recommend to pipe both sources with take(1) to cause the completion.